# ACF field groups is not loading in acf/include_fields hook with php code as ACF doc suggests

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF latest version 6.2.3 and trying to load the field group from the php code generated from another site. Both sites are using free version of ACF
The code is

```
add_action( 'acf/include_fields', function() {
if ( ! function_exists( 'acf_add_local_field_group' ) ) {
    return;
}

acf_add_local_field_group( array(
    'key' => 'group_65685566476a1',
    'title' => 'Test group cybercraft',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_65685567f769f',
            'label' => 'Test',
            'name' => 'test',
            'aria-label' => '',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'post',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => '',
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
    'show_in_rest' => 0,
) );
```

} );

I placed it in the new site, but it is not working. Verifying that the code is run by the site but no field group inserted in acf field group list .
Is there anything that I have missed to do ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you perhaps fail to take into account, what https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/#getting-started has to say? _"Note: Field Groups and Fields registered via code will not be visible/editable via the “Edit Field Groups” admin page."_

Comment: Thanks for point me the note. Yes, got it.